# Prove the limit of a near integer function by the epsilon-delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, functions, epsilon-delta

I have to prove the limits of the following function define as $f:\mathbb{R} \setminus\{2\} \to \mathbb{R}$. 
$$ f(x) = \frac{\left[ x - 2 \right]}{x - 2} $$

Limits to demonstrate:
$$ \lim_{x \to 2^+} f(x), \quad \lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x) \quad \text{ and } \quad \lim_{x \to 2} f(x). $$

---

I tried to demonstrate the first exists if $\forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists\delta>0$ such as
\begin{align}
x < x - 2 < \delta &\implies \left| \frac{\left[x-2\right]}{x-2} - 0 \right| < \epsilon \\
&\implies \frac{\left[ x - 2 \right]}{x-2} < \epsilon \\
&
\end{align}
But I dont know how to manipulate the RHS to get the samething as the LHS.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is $[x-2]$ for x close to 2? (For example, 2.4?)

Comment: I suppose $x$ will be $0$ either way...

Comment: But how can I define $\delta(\epsilon)$?

Comment: My question will be, do I have to pick a minimum or a maximum value for delta!?